# Python Pandas: Dividindo um DataFrame em várias partes com base nas linhas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, divisão

Tenho um DataFrame no Pandas.

Gostaria de dividi-lo em x partes e então atribuir cada uma dessas partes a um critério.

Algo como pegar um DF de 90 linhas, dividi-lo em 3 partes e então atribuir as linhas 1-30 ao critério A, 31-60 ao critério B e 61-90 ao critério C.

Essa atribuição pode ser criando uma coluna nova, novos DFs, tanto faz, e o conteúdo da linha teria que ir completo, com todas as colunas e tal.

A operação seria feita diariamente, com o nº de linhas e de critérios podendo variar.

Alguém sugere uma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Mostre o que já tentou fazer, mostre também uma saída esperada. Outro ponto importante são dados para teste.

Answer (score 0):

rapaz, pensei dessa forma aqui:
você passando o número de critérios e quais seria eles:

```
num_criterios = 5
lista_criterios = ['A','B','C','D','E']
lista_criterios_df = []
```

Usando dois for para preencher a lista que será adicionada ao df, logo um dos for tem o número de linhas do df e o outro vai ficar alterando entre as classificações passadas, ali também temos uma verificação para garantir que a lista final tenha o comprimento igual ao numero de linhas do df.

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
  for j in range(num_criterios):
    if len(lista_criterios_df) < df.shape[0]:
      lista_criterios_df.append(lista_criterios[j])
```

Por fim adicionamos ao df atribuindo a uma nova coluna.

```
df['Nova Categoria'] = lista_criterios_df
df
```

[image: segue uma captura de tela do meu colab]

Espero ter te ajudado!

Comment: A ideia era essa mesma, cara. Adaptei aqui e funcionou direitinho! Muito obrigado mesmo!!